# Facing issue when trying to host CI website on a2hosting. my php version is 7.4 ,Ci version is 4

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, continuous-integration

This is the error I am facing when trying to host CI website on a2hosting. my php version is 7.4 ,Ci version is 4:

```
    'Code Igniter\Database\MySQL I\Connection' not found
in SYSTEMPATH/Database/Database.php on line 136.
 1 SYSTEMPATH/Database/Database.php(56): CodeIgniter\Database\Database->initDriver('MySQLI', 'CodeIgniter\\Database\\MySQLI\\Connection', [...])
 2 SYSTEMPATH/Database/Config.php(78): CodeIgniter\Database\Database->load([...], 'default')
 3 SYSTEMPATH/Model.php(136): CodeIgniter\Database\Config::connect('default')
 4 APPPATH/Controllers/Home.php(10): CodeIgniter\Model->__construct()
 5 SYSTEMPATH/CodeIgniter.php(898): App\Controllers\Home->index()
 6 SYSTEMPATH/CodeIgniter.php(457): CodeIgniter\CodeIgniter->runController(Object(App\Controllers\Home))
 7 SYSTEMPATH/CodeIgniter.php(340): CodeIgniter\CodeIgniter->handleRequest(null, Object(Config\Cache), false)
 8 FCPATH/index.php(67): CodeIgniter\CodeIgniter->run()
```

Comment: There is space in `Code Igniter` and `MySQL I` in the error message that may appears in your code as class name. Check your code to make sure that you write it correctly.

Comment: Sir there is typing mistake. in my code nothing space between codeigniter and mysqli

Comment: In that case, you should paste the exact error message without any modification. Because `Code Igniter\Database\MySQL I\Connection` is not the same with `CodeIgniter\Database\MySQLI\Connection`

Comment: Look at the source code of CodeIgniter's Connection class [here](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/develop/system/Database/MySQLi/Connection.php), the namespace and class is `CodeIgniter\Database\MySQLi\Connection`. Make sure that you type it correctly.